# Error with tag toLabel to a field of a related object

Tags: apex, soql, picklist, label

I have a simple query of a custom object with a lookup to Account object:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Client__r.MyPicklistField__c, tolabel(Client__r.MyPicklistField__c) MyPicklistFieldLabel
FROM MyCustomObject__c
```

I can execute this query with "Salesforce Inpector" and "Developer Console", but if I execute the code in lwc, I get a error:

```
FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: No such column 'MyPicklistFieldLabel' on entity 'Account'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

Controller:

```
    @AuraEnabled
public static List<MyCustomObject__c> init(){
    return [SELECT Id, Name, Client__r.MyPicklistField__c, tolabel(Client__r.MyPicklistField__c) MyPicklistFieldLabel
FROM MyCustomObject__c];
}
```

What is the reason?

Thanks,
Greetings

Comment: Can you post your LWC code please?

Comment: @MartinLezer LWC only calls the apex function. When the query is invoked it fails with the mentioned error. But if I execute the query in the develoer console if it works

Comment: Your SOQL is trying to provide an alias for the toLabel but you are not actually defining an aggregate query which is where aliases can be defined. Remove the alias.

Comment: @PhilW Is it not possible to indicate an alias to a field of a related object? On a field of the same object if I can, and executing this query individually in the developer also works